# How to prevent listview caching

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-listview

**Context:**

I have an activity that lists all message threads returned by a cursor and I bind them to a ListView.

**What I aim at:**

I would like to customize any row of the ListView according to any value of the cursor. I mean if the thread contains not read messages, I want to set the textcolor to blue (=> "not read").

**The problem is:**

The Listview does cache some views while scrolling so some threads with all messages read appear randomly in blue.

I tried all of these option but it kept caching:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
view.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
view.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
view.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(false);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
view.setWillNotCacheDrawing(true);
view.invalidate();
```

Any advice?

---

**EDIT 1**

I tried to override bindView this way in a class that extends SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

    TextView tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

    //we set the name of the src/dst of the msg
    tv_name.setText(c.getString(5));

    //if there are not read msg, we set the textColor to BLUE
    if (cursor.getInt(8) != 0){

            tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    }
```

}

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override its `bindView` method

Comment: I tried so but it remains caching the views...

Comment: set the text color to blue or black in bindView,  the whole idea of the ListView is to reuse the views

Comment: That's exactly what i tried.
However, the textstyle is not updated. Maybe I should not use a ListView?

Comment: it is,  in CursorAdapter it is the only plsce where you update the item views,  what's your code of bindView? btw if you don't want to override bindView you can use default implementation  and use ViewBinder

Comment: I added the code to the initial post.

Comment: and where is `tv_name.setTextColor(BLACK_OR_ANY_OTHER_DEFAULT_COLOR);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (cursor.getInt(8) != 0){
        tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
} else{
        // set text to the default color
        tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);       
}
```

Since the view used in listView is recycled, you need to handle all the cases.

Comment: Hm. I thought I did have tried this. It seems that I was mistaken since IT DOES WORK! Thanks for helping. You saved my weekend.